# Have functions with this scaling behavior been studied? Do they have a special name?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

In attempting to understand the mathematical content of certain dimensional analysis procedures one encounters in mathematics, physics, and engineering, I've noticed it's useful to understand functions having certain generalized homogeneity/scaling properties:

Given a $k$-by-$n$ matrix with rational entries $A = (a_{ij})$ and $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_k)\in \mathbb R^n_+$, define a transformation $S_{A,\lambda}:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ as follows:
$$
  S_{A,\lambda}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda_1^{a_{11}}\lambda_2^{a_{21}}\cdots\lambda_k^{a_{k1}}x_1 \\
  \lambda_1^{a_{12}}\lambda_2^{a_{22}}\cdots\lambda_k^{a_{k2}}x_2 \\
  \vdots \\
  \lambda_1^{a_{1n}}\lambda_2^{a_{2n}}\cdots\lambda_k^{a_{kn}}x_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now suppose that there exists such an $A$ and rational numbers $\Delta_1, \Delta_2, \dots, \Delta_k$, such that $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ satisfies
$$
  f(S_{A,\lambda}(x)) = \lambda_1^{\Delta_1}\lambda_2^{\Delta_2}\cdots\lambda_k^{\Delta_k}f(x)
$$
for all $\lambda\in\mathbb R^n_+$.

In the special case:

- $A$ is the identity matrix,
- all $\lambda_i$ are equal, and
- the $\Delta_i$ sum to $m$,

I believe $f$ would be called a homogeneous function of degree $m$.

Is there a special name for such functions $f$ when there are no such restrictions on $A$, $\lambda_i$, and $\Delta_i$?  Have they been studied in some generality?

Comment: Is this related to the "dimensionful matrices" Dan Piponi talks about [here](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2016/08/dimensionful-matrices.html)? If so maybe there is more in Hart's *[Multidimensional Analysis](http://www.georgehart.com/research/multanal.html)* book.

Comment: After reading the text in those links, I'm skeptical that multidimensional analysis is necessary -- I think one just needs "scalar" dimensional analysis as they put it.  However, somehow the pages you suggested got me to an article by Whitney that seems to kind of discuss this stuff in its approach to dimensional analysis in sections 20-23: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2314953?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents